# Can this integral be expressed in terms of elementary functions? $\int\frac{\ln(2+x^2)}{1+x^2}dx.$

Tags: calculus, integration

If the following primitive can be computed, can someone show me the way ?

$$\int\frac{\ln(2+x^2)}{1+x^2}dx.$$

I tried substituting $x$ with $\tan(t)$ but the integral didn't get much simpler.

Comment: Yes, according to [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integral+of+(ln(2%2Bx^2)]%2F(1%2Bx^2)). But is isn't nice looking.

Comment: It can be integrated using dilogarithms. Do you consider them to be "elementary"?

Comment: Why is it that people ask seemingly impossible integration questions here?

Comment: @Victor In that case, if it is not elementary then one can prove it by elementary means, but that involves knowing a lttle bit about how integration algorithms work. Search for "Risch" in prior answers to find examples and references.

Comment: $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln\Big(x^2+a^2\Big)}{x^2+b^2}dx=\frac\pi b\cdot\ln(a+b)$.

Comment: @Lucian How does that *definite* integral help with this *indefinite* integral?

Comment: @BillDubuque: It is quite possible that that's why the OP is asking even the question in the first place.